# Game character move different speed in different screen size, libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, screen

I'm trying to make a game with libGDX in which a game character will move across screen horizontally. And I made a sample with following code and tested on a phone(smaller width) and tablet(larger width). The actor move and disappear faster in phone than in tablet. How can I fix this?

```
public class SpriteMoveTestGame extends Game {

private MyScreen screen;

@Override
public void create() {
    screen = new MyScreen();
    setScreen(screen);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
}

private class MyActor extends Actor {

    private Texture texture;
    private float x;

    public MyActor() {
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));
        x = 0.0f;
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 0);
        batch.draw(texture, x, 200);
        x += 4.5f;
    }
}

private class MyScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

    private Stage stage;
    private FitViewport fitViewport;
    private MyActor actor;

    public MyScreen() {
        stage = new Stage();
        actor = new MyActor();
        stage.addActor(actor);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        super.render(delta);
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you are using a fitviewport without a camera, so it depends only on the screen resolution. So if the phone has a 800 width resolution (for example) and the table has 1080, it will reach the edge of the screen faster on the phone. You need to use a camera (OrthographicCamera) that will tell libgdx how many pixeles/units you want to show always independly of the screen, and to avoid scretching, use ExtendViewport instead of Fitviewport.

Comment: Unrelated, but don't put your glclear call in your actor. That clears the whole screen so it should only be done once by the game or screen, not inside actors.

Comment: @OscarO. Will you please provide a sample code?

Comment: I don't know how they know what type of viewport you're using. Nevertheless it sounds like you are your using Viewports incorrectly. There are plenty of examples in the LibGDX wiki or you could show us your code where you work with the viewport and we can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 in the sample code he posted the FitViewport is used

Comment: Oh, I see. But it's private and never assigned.

Answer (score 0):

As Oscar has said you do not use any camera or viewport so you use the screen resolution. If the width of the phone is 800 and the table's width is 1200 and every frame you do `actor.x += 20` the actor has 40 frames on phone and 60 frames on tablet to cross the hole width.

To initial a Stage with a Fitviewport:

```
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private FitViewport viewport;
private Stage stage;

@Override
public void show() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(200, 200, camera);
    stage = new Stage(viewport);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height);
}
```

Now you have a Stage with a viewport of 200 x 200 units.
When you now run the app the actor will have on both devices, phone and tablet 10 frames from left to the rigth side.

Last problem is that you maybe have a very old phone and it's a little bit slow. Your old phone need 0.02 sec for a frame while your tablet only need 0.016 sec for a frame.
 So the actor on tablet is a little bit faster than on the phone.

You think: "My actor can run 20 units in 1 sec." so first you do: `actor.x += 20;`

But the problem is that the actor now runs 20 units in a frame not in a second. 
To solve the problem you multiply 20 by delta time between this and the last frame: `actor.x += 20 * delta;` (`delta` is in `act(float delta)` method):

```
@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    x += 20 * delta;
}
```

Now your actor always run 20 units in 1 sec and on each device you see a 200 unit width world. So on every device the actor has 10 sec from the left to the right side.